# css keyframes transition not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations, keyframe

I far as am aware i have done everything correct in my css in order to get the following transition [click](http://plnkr.co/edit/YRzOYU3gIBa1OfGOBSA0?p=preview) to work in firefox. However this bounce in transition doesn't seem to be working in the firefox browser. although firefox supports keyframes. below is a snippet of my code...

```
 .animate {
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
 -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
-o-animation-fill-mode: both;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-o-animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-duration: 1s;
}


 .animate.hinge {
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
 -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
 -o-animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-duration: 1s;
}


 @-moz-keyframes bounceIn {
 /* line 83, ../sass/style.scss */
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
}

/* line 86, ../sass/style.scss */
50% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
}

/* line 91, ../sass/style.scss */
70% {
-webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
 }

/* line 95, ../sass/style.scss */
 100% {
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
 }
}


 @keyframes bounceIn {
  /* line 119, ../sass/style.scss */
  0% {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.3);
  }

 /* line 124, ../sass/style.scss */
 50% {
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(1.05);
 }

 /* line 129, ../sass/style.scss */
  70% {
   transform: scale(0.9);
  }

 /* line 133, ../sass/style.scss */
  100% {
transform: scale(1);
 }
 }

 /* line 139, ../sass/style.scss */
 .block {
 -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
 -moz-animation-name: bounceIn;
  -o-animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-name: bounceIn;
 }
```

Am i missing a certain prefix or am i using a animate property that is not supported in ff

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-moz` prefix for the transform properties instead of `-webkit` within the `@-moz-keyframe`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/SQeyM/1/) - it works (FF only for demonstration purposes)

```
@-moz-keyframes bounceIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    }

    70% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Also, with the current CSS you would use the following HTML:

```
<div class="block animate"></div>
```

I included both the `.block` and the `.animate` class. (The animate class contains the animation duration).

Comment: Well spotted but it still doesn't actually work, i have uploaded an edited version on plunker. you can test for yourself

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock I updated it with a jsFiddle example. Try it in FF.

Comment: I already had the HTML structured that way. For some strange this transition isn't working for me on FF

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock Alright. Does it work when you look at this example? http://jsfiddle.net/tJt4m/

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock I put `infinite` on there. I doesn't seem like that's what you want; but if you removed that, then it should be the desired results. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42748/discussion-between-newkidontheblock-and-joshc)

Answer (score 0):

```
.animate {
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
 -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
-o-animation-fill-mode: both;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-o-animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-duration: 1s;
}


 .animate.hinge {
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
 -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
 -o-animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-duration: 1s;
}


 @-moz-keyframes bounceIn {
 /* line 83, ../sass/style.scss */
0% {
opacity: 0;
-moz-transform: scale(0.3);
}

/* line 86, ../sass/style.scss */
50% {
opacity: 1;
-moz-transform: scale(1.05);
}

/* line 91, ../sass/style.scss */
70% {
-moz-transform: scale(0.9);
 }

/* line 95, ../sass/style.scss */
 100% {
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
 }
}


 @keyframes bounceIn {
  /* line 119, ../sass/style.scss */
  0% {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.3);
  }

 /* line 124, ../sass/style.scss */
 50% {
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(1.05);
 }

 /* line 129, ../sass/style.scss */
  70% {
   transform: scale(0.9);
  }

 /* line 133, ../sass/style.scss */
  100% {
transform: scale(1);
 }
 }

 /* line 139, ../sass/style.scss */
 .block {
 -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
 -moz-animation-name: bounceIn;
  -o-animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-name: bounceIn;
 }
```